# ReactJS: How many times is a mapped component's constructor called?

Tags: reactjs, constructor, components, render, array.prototype.map

I have a React Component that is rendered multiple times using Array.prototype.map() inside another component.

How many times should the first component's constructor be called?  I was expecting as many times as the length of the mapped array, but it seems it's only called once.

In my specific code, it is called just before the last render().

Sample code:

```
class ComponentB extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props) // added upon first reply
    this.handleObjectAdd = this.handleObject.bind(this);
    this.state.objects = [];
  }

  handleObjectAdd() {
    this.state.objects.unshift({prop1: this.state.objects.length + 1});
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.handleObjectAdd}>ADD</button>
          { this.state.objects.map((object, index) =>
              <ComponentA key={index} details={object}/>
            )
          }
        </div>
      )
    })
  }
}

class ComponentA extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props) // added upon first reply
    console.log('ComponentA constructor called');
  }
  render() {
    console.log('ComponentA render() called');
    return (
      <input type="text" value={this.props.details.prop1}></input>
    )
  }
}
```

For an array of 5 elements (all ComponentA instances) I get the following lines:

```
ComponentA render() called
ComponentA render() called
ComponentA render() called
ComponentA render() called
ComponentA constructor called
ComponentA render() called
```

Also, the log line for the constructor always appears before the last constructor log line, regardless of the number of array elements.

Why is the log output such as above?  Would appreciate any insight.

This was flagged as a duplicate of [React Rerender dynamic Components (Solr)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45595458/react-rerender-dynamic-components-solr), but it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your question as "why when I put new element to the very start of array it seems new React component is created for the very last element?"

The reason is `key` that you make to use with `index`.

Based on its logic(check [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) section in docs) since only last element(with new index as `oldLength + 1`) has unique `key` only it will be created from scratch. While all others are just re-rendered and updated. In other words your code updates `N - 1` elements instead of just creating 1 new and leaving all other unchanged.

To handle that you should not rely on `index` in `key` but use some other predictable, stable and unqiue value. In your case it's `prop1`. Then constructor will be called for the very first element.

Here is updated version

```
class ComponentB extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props) // added upon first reply
    this.state = {
      objects: []
    };
  }

  handleObjectAdd = () => {
    this.setState(oldState => ({
      objects: [
          {prop1: this.state.objects.length + 1}, 
          ...oldState.objects
      ]
    }))
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleObjectAdd}>ADD</button>
        {this.state.objects.map(obj =>
          <ComponentA key={obj.prop1} details={obj} />
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class ComponentA extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props) // added upon first reply
    console.log('ComponentA constructor called');
  }
  render() {
    console.log('ComponentA render() called');
    return (
      <input type="text" value={this.props.details.prop1}></input>
    )
  }
}
```

Your initial code has few syntax errors and mutated state directly(never do that) so it did never re-render after button clicked. Please check code next time you post a question - it'd make understanding/answering much easier.

[UPD] extracted some slice from comments below

> instead of just creating 1 new and leaving all other unchanged.

React does not try to minimize operations count. While comparing [1,2,3] and [0, 1, 2, 3] there are 2 possible ways: either 'insert 0 at the beginning, shifting everything else' or 'decrement all the elements by 1 and additionally insert 3 at the end'. If you provide good property as a key React picks up 1st solution. But having key={index} you are literally says 'React, use 2nd approach, I know what I'm doing'. React does not analyze code you run before calling .setState, it just relies on key value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  My mistake for posting an older code which I have since fixed (the part of mutating state) in my actual code.  I appreciate your explanation with the keys as well, which reinforced my understanding on lists and keys.  You answered why there was only one call to the constructor (I had a hard time understanding why it's not repeatedly called).  My other question was: why is it called on the 2nd to the last element, when I add the new element at the beginning of the list?  I will leave the mistakes up there in my initial code.

Comment: look, React does not try to minimize operations count. While comparing `[1,2,3]` and `[0, 1, 2, 3]` there are 2 possible ways: either 'insert 0 at the beginning, shifting everything else' or 'decrement all the elements by 1 and additionally insert 3 at the end'. If you provide good property as a `key` React picks up 1st solution. But having `key={index}` you are literally says 'React, use 2nd approach, I know what I'm doing'. React does not analyze code you run before calling `.setState`, it just relies on `key` value.

Comment: I think I understand now why it's called just before the last render:  The last call to render is actually for the last element added (at the beginning of the list, in this case), not for he last element (existing in the list).  So, I think React calls the renders for the existing element, then calls the constructor for the new element, then calls the render for this new element.

Comment: yep, exactly. last one is created and next is rendered.

Comment: your last comment on react minimizing operations was very helpful in understanding the docs about keys and indexes.  thanks